# Later.js schedule 1 week before

Tags: javascript, laterjs

Using [later.js](https://bunkat.github.io/later/index.html) through [synced-cron on meteor](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) I am scheduling a notification one week before an event's `event.date`. Here are 3 examples, top 2 functional but undesired, the 3rd a non-functional attempt at what I wanted.

`notify.js`:

```
SyncedCron.add({
    name: id,
    schedule: function(parser) {

        // 1) This works as expected (but not what I want)
        // Returns notification at 00:00 same date as event.

        return parser.recur().on(event.date).fullDate();


        // 2) This works as expected (but not what I want)
        // Returns notification at 06:00 today.

        return parser.recur().on(6).hour().before(event.date).fullDate();


        // 2) This, and other permutations tried, does not work
        // returns error: "Exception while invoking method 
        // 'scheduleNotification' TypeError: Cannot call method 
        // 'getTime' of undefined"

        return parser.recur().hour(6).before(event.date).fullDate();
    },
    job: function() {
        notify();
    }
});
```

Can anyone suggest a way to set the notification for a given time before a date object? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing event.date with standard javascript functions rather than invoking any special later properties.

```
    schedule: function(parser) {
        var notificationDate = event.date;
        notificationDate.setDate(event.date.getDate() - 7);
        notificationDate.setHours(19);
        return parser.recur().on(eventDate).fullDate();
            .and()
            .on(event.date).fullDate();
    },
```

So `notificationDate` is set relative to any given event date.